# Strange `joinable()` behavior with std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I'm trying to implement a list of threads where one thread communicates to the next via `std::thread::join` that it is finished until all the jobs are accomplished.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::vector<std::thread> workers;

void f1(void)
{
  std::cout<<"begin f1"<<std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cout<<"end f1"<<std::endl;
}

void f2(int sleep_for, std::thread & previous_thread)
{
  try
  {
    previous_thread.join();
    std::cout<<"begin f2"<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout<<"end f2"<<std::endl;
  }
  catch (const std::system_error& ex)
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << ex.code() << '\n';
    ss << ex.code().message() << '\n';
    ss << ex.what() << '\n';
    printf("%s",ss.str().c_str());
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  std::cout<<0<<std::endl;
  workers.emplace_back(&f1);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    std::cout<<i+1<<std::endl;
    workers.emplace_back(&f2, i, std::ref(workers.back()));
  }
  workers.back().join();
  /*
  std::thread t(&f1);
  std::thread t1(&f2, 0, std::ref(t));
  std::thread t2(&f2, 1, std::ref(t1));                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  std::thread t3(&f2, 2, std::ref(t2));
  t3.join();
  */
  return 0;
}
```

In this code you can see I am spinning up 4 threads and every thread after the first should `join` on the previous thread so it will wait for it to finish.  However I am getting error 22s (invalid argument) which according to the docs means that `joinable()` is false in some cases.

Sometimes execution does make it past all the threading but then an exception is thrown in `~thread` which causes the program to crash just before exiting.

What am I doing wrong here? The docs are really straight forward on this so I'm not sure what I'm missing

Edit: the answer I marked as correct does point out the problem with the code but the solution i chose was to use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`

Comment: A better choice is to `reserve` enough space in the vector before you start adding to it so it doesn't reallocate. Or if that's not enough, use a `std::deque` instead of `std::list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workers.emplace_back(&f2, i, std::ref(workers.back()));`

This results in UB as you pass pointer to workers's data and then increase it's size which potentially reallocates all its members causing the reference to invalidate.

Comment: Beat me to it!  The problem can be resolved by calling `workers.resize (5)` before doing anything else.  `std::thread` is moveable, but moving them is enough to trigger UB.

Comment: Ah! So this would actually be one of those situations where `std::list` is appropriate?

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah. Though, go be more accurate `workers.reserve(5);` is a more appropriate fix as it doesn't require any other changes in the code.

Comment: @Tyler ... well no. Use `vector<unique_ptr<thread>>` or use a `map` that doesn't make any reallocations. Honestly, I don't think that this is a good idea to pass `thread` to another while keeping its reference to oneself. Other types are used for thread synchronization like future, condition_variable, mutex...

Comment: @ALX23z Sorry, I meant to say `reserve`!

Comment: Ah gotcha,  sorry I didn't mean it was the only solution just one that would fix this.

Comment: @Tyler You are right that `std::list` would be a possible fix. `std::list` has very few practical use cases, but one of it's advantages is that elements don't get invalidated by anything except removal.